# Make the document un tracked changeable in Word 2013

Tags: ms-word, ms-office

On word-2013, I am unable to understand that what happened to my word document. The line I want to delete or change is going to cut with a red color and remains in the document as showing the picture below.

[image]

I want to get rid from it. Any solution to get rid it off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Review Tab in the Ribbon you have enabled the Track Changes option and set the Markup option most likely to "All Markup".

If you want to keep track of changes leave this enabled but set your Markup option to either "No Markup" or "Simple Markup". Otherwise just disable Track Changes.

Your question is not a developer question, you are most likely better served when you ask questions like this on SuperUser.com

To serve developers looking for a solution in code, turning Markup off in VBA can be done like this:

```
With ActiveWindow.View.RevisionsFilter
    .Markup = wdRevisionsMarkupNone
    .View = wdRevisionsViewFinal
End With
```

Comment: Perfect. Made me.